# Algorithm suitable for a region-growing image segmentation based on the minimization of a metric

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

Is there a pixel-based `region growing` algorithm that can be employed for the extraction of features (`segmentation`) on an image, by adding pixels to the `seed` based on the minimization of a certain `metric`. Potentially, a pixel can be removed if the `metric` is not optimized when this pixel is added (i.e. possibility to backtrack and go back to the `seed` obtained in the previous iterations).

I'll try to explain further my objectives:

1. This algorithm starts from a `central pixel` selected as an `initial seed` on the image.
2. Afterwards, each of the `4 neighbors` is explored (`right`, `left`, `bottom` and `top` neighbors) separately, to see if the `metric` is optimized by growing the seed in the selected direction.
3. A `neighboring pixel` might not optimize the `metric` immediately, even if the `seed` created by adding this pixel will be optimal in future iterations.
4. There is a possibility that a `neighboring pixel` is added to the seed but is removed later, if the obtained `seed` is not optimal.

Can anyone suggest to me an `Artificial Intelligence` technique (or a `greedy approach`) that is adequate to solve this kind of problems? Also, what would be a good criteria to judge that the addition of a pixel will optimize the metric even though this will probably happen in future iterations.

**P.S:** I started implementing what's explained above in `Python` but was stuck in the issue of determining if a `path` (`neighboring pixel`) is worth exploring or not. Right now, I try to add a `neighboring pixel` only if the `seed` produced improve (i.e. minimize) the `error` relatively to the metric. However, even though by adding the `right` or `left` neighbors the `metric` isn't optimized, one of these two `paths` might lead to the optimal solution in the future (as explained in the third objective).

Comment: Do you already have a metric by which to compare pixel regions or do you need to create one as well?

Comment: @Aabglov I guess I do since by `metric` I meant I have a sort of `ground truth` I'm comparing to. Basically, in every iteration a `seed` is constructed and the value of the `metric` estimated for this `seed` is compared to the `ground truth` to tell if by adding the `neighboring pixel` the `metric` is optimized.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you're saying. Do you have a maximum size for the feature(s)? I don't need to know what it is, just if there is a maximum size that's less than that of the input image

Comment: Have a look at Chan-Vese method: formulate your minimization problem in variational form, solve Euler-Lagrange equations and evolve from the seed point using the level set method. It's not 4-neighbours but implicit curve, nevertheless resembles your objectives.

Comment: @Aabglov I'm trying to reconstruct a building but I don't really have a maximum size for this kind of features. If this information will be useful during the `segmentation` I will try to find a way to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically outlined the most successful algorithm you could get with this approach.  It's success will depend heavily on the metric you use to add/remove pixels, but there are a few things you can do to emulate the behavior you want.

### Definitions

We'll call the metric we're optimizing `M` where `M(R)` is the metric's value for a region `R` and a region `R` is some collections of pixels.  I will assume that optimizing the metric will result in the largest possible value of `M`, but this approach can work if the goal is to minimize `M` as well.

### Methodology

This approach is going to be slightly backwards to your original outline, but it should satisfy both requirements of adding pixels that lie in non-optimal paths from the seed and removing pixels that do not contribute significantly to the optimization.

We will begin at a seed `s`, but instead of evaluating paths as we go we will add **all** pixels in the image (or maximum feature size) iteratively to our region.  At each step we will determine a value of the pixel based on how much it improves the metric for the current region, `M(p)`. This is **not** the same as the value of the region containing the pixel (`M(R)` where `p` is in `R`).  Rather it would be the difference of the value of the region containing the pixel and the value of the region before the pixel was added (`M(p) = M(R) - M(R') where R = R' + p`).  If you have the capacity to evaluate a single pixel you could simply use that instead.

The next change is to include an regularization parameter in `M(R)` that penalizes the score based on the number of pixels included: `N(R) = M(R) - a * |R|` where `a` is some arbitrary positive constant and `|R|` represents the cardinality (number of pixels) in our region.  **Note**: if the goal is to minimize `M` then `a` should be negative. This will have the effect of penalizing the score of the region if it includes too many pixels.

Finally, after all pixels have been added to the region and `N(p)` has been evaluated for each pixel we iterate over the region again.  This time we begin at the last pixel added and iterate backwards over our set of pixels, ending at the seed `s`.  At each iteration determine the score of the region `N(R)`.  If the score `N(R)` has **decreased** since the last iteration then we remove the pixel `p` with the lowest score `N(p)`.  This should have the effect of the smallest number of pixels in the region that contribute the most to the score.

### Additional Considerations

If the remaining pixels lie on non-contiguous paths after pruning you could run a secondary algorithm to add in adjoining pixels.  You'll need to do testing to determine an optimal value of `a` such that enough pixels are kept to reconstruct the building, but it doesn't include every pixel from the image.

### My Opinion (that you didn't ask for)

In general I think you would have more luck with more robust algorithms such as [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) for feature classification.  They'll likely be faster and definitely more accurate than the algorithm described above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aabglov this seems like a valid solution although a little bit complex and as you said It's not sure that it will give a solution eventually. I have however few questions: why did you penalize regions that are bigger in size (using the `a` constant)? and when you're moving backwards (from an `implementation` point of view), if you remove just the `pixel` with lowest metric value, does it mean that the the three remaining neighbors are kept in the region? or are you keeping the `pixels` added to the region in a sort of `queue` (to keep track of the order)?

Comment: @h4k1m the penalization is to ensure that only the most effective pixels are kept.  You want to ensure that not all pixels from the image are added to the region, only those most likely to be part of the feature you're identifying.  This parameter also rewards the removal of pixels in the reverse iterative step.  When a pixel is removed from the region only it is removed.  All neighbors are left.  If this results in holes they can be back-filled later in a post-processing step.

Comment: You (@Aabglov) mentioned `Convolutional neural networks` for the segmentation of features on images. But, can it be applied in a `unsupervised` way?

Comment: @h4k1m do you mean unsupervised in the sense that it can learn to identify buildings without labeled training data or that it can learn to extract only buildings from an image after it's been trained?

Comment: @h4k1m There's been some impressive results using Convolutional Autoencoders (which are stacked Convolutional Neural Networks trained to represent their input).  I would recommend looking into Autoencoders (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) and then trying to integrate Convolutional layers.